# Bonds, interest rates and inflation

Tags: investing, bonds, interest-rate, inflation

I was reading *Learn to Earn* by Peter Lynch and I came across a paragraph that has confused me to say the least. It is regarding bonds -

> If you buy a $10,000 ten-year bond and hold it for ten years, you get your
>   money back plus interest, and nothing more. Actually, you get back much less
>   because of inflation. Let’s say the bond is paying 8 percent a year, and the
>   inflation rate over that ten-year period is 4 percent. Even though you’ve
>   collected $8,000 in interest payments, you’ve lost almost $1,300 to inflation.
>   Your original $10,000 investment is now worth $6,648 after ten years of 4
>   percent annual inflation. So the whole ten-year investment has left you with
>   less than a 3 percent annual return, and that’s before taxes. If you figure in the taxes, your return approaches zero.

I can calculate the interest payment as $8,000. I can also see how the investment of $10,000 is now worth only $6,648 after ten years of 4 percent annual inflation.

But my question is, how do we arrive at "lost almost $1,300" part? Would be great if you could explain.

Comment: I'd assume he means that you've lost $1,300 of your $8,000 in interest to inflation ($800 each year eroded by 4%), but I get ~$1,565 not $1,300, so it's unclear to me.

Comment: @HartCO Could you tell me how you arrived at ~$1,565? 
At 4% annual inflation, the $8,000 interest comes to be $5,318. That gives me a loss of $2,682

Comment: I assumed you get 10 $800 interest payments. So year one, 800 * 0.96 (4% inflation) = 768 + 800 (year 2 interest) * 0.96 = 1,505.28... etc. by year 10 instead of $8,000 interest you only have $6,435.21, $1,565 less than $8,000.  That doesn't help explain his $1,300.

Comment: One year return of 8% with 4% inflation is inflation  adjusted return of 3.85%, no?  (1.08/1.04-1).  Quote says "... has left you with less than a 3 percent annual return."  FUBAR?

Comment: Without getting in to the relative merits of being concerned with the inflation boogy-man, logically, shouldn't the risk free investment option have a net-net return of close to zero?  You're being paid a nominal amount for your loss of liquidity.  You never assumed any real investment risk why would anyone expect real investment reward?

Comment: @BobBaerker Since the bond interest doesn't compound (assuming you sat on it and didn't re-invest) the inflation compounds that first year's 3.85% away, only in year 10 would it be 3.85%.

Comment: @Hart Co - What would the number be if the interest was re-invested, assuming constant yield over the period?

Comment: I'm not sure what the point of mentioning inflation is. Inflation affects _all_ investments, so I don't know why he's only applying it to bonds.

Comment: After reading that paragraph about 10 times I would argue that you should pick something else to read.

Comment: I'm still getting about $12k after 10 years with $18k*.96^10 .... So it's still far more value in 10 years. Also where can I get an 8% bond and why are we calculating 4% inflation ?

Comment: What a strange calculation. You don't "lose" anything to inflation - seeing as the alternative is just holding cash. If you held cash for 10 years, you'd have less than half the purchasing power remaining. Holding bonds, you'd have a bit more. Thus, you gained some. Bonds are just a little less liquid form of cash - it's hardly an "investment".

Answer (score 2):

This passage seems designed to confuse rather than teach.  However:

Amount of principle lost to inflation: 
10000*.96^10 = $6648

Amount of interest lost to inflation (compounded yearly and assuming you don't reinvest):
800*.96^9+800*.96^8+800*.96^7+800*.96^6+800*.96^5+800*.96^4+800*.96^3+800*.96^2+800*.96^1+800 = $6703

The second number seems to be the "lost almost $1,300" (of the $8000 interest).

Answer (score 0):

It appears that Mr. Lynch made liberal use of first-order approximations to elaborate his point.

According to his math:

```
$6,648 present value of bond = $10,000 face value * (1-0.04 inflation)^10
"Lost to inflation" = present value - face value ≅ -$1300

# (I'm guessing a bit on this next one)
"less than a 3 percent annual return" 
    = ((1+(interest rate * 10))/(1+(inflation rate * 10)))-1 / 10
    = (1.8/1.4)-1 / 10
    = 0.0286
```

These are arithmetic approximations of what should be a [geometric](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/g/geometricmean.asp) calculation. I don't believe this is a contentious topic. Please look at [an explanation of inflation discounting](https://faculty.washington.edu/toths/ESRM461/Textbook/Ch3_Inflation.pdf) or Google another one if you prefer.

If you want to know what the rate of return on an investment is after inflation:

```
real rate = (1 + interest rate)/(1 + inflation rate) - 1
          = 1.08 / 1.04 -1
          = 0.038
```